# Let $Z=Z(x,y)$ be a solution of $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ = 1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $Z=Z(x,y)$ be a solution of $$\frac{\partial z}{∂x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 1$$ passing through $(0,0,0)$. Then $Z(0,1)$ is
>
> 1. 0
> 2. 1
> 3. 2
> 4. 4

By Charpit Method I get the solution as $Z=ax+by+c$ whare $a, b, c$ are constant and $ab=1$.
since $Z$ passes through the origin then $c=0$.
finally we get the solution  $Z=ax+by$.
then $Z(0,1)= b$. Ather that what will I do?

Comment: The only restriction I see is that the first answer ($Z(0,1)=0$) cannot be true. In fact, if $b=0$, then you cannot satisfy $ab=1$. Any other value of $b$ is correct.

Comment: @AugSB, apparently, the answer key says b=0 is the only possible answer!

Comment: If $b=0$, then $Z=ax$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=0$, so $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=0$. On the other hand, for $b\ne0$ and $ab=1$, one has $Z(x,y)=\frac{x}{b}+bx$, which satisfies $Z(0,0)=0$, $Z(0,1)=b$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\frac{1}{b}b=1$. I do not see how it can be $Z(0,1)=0$...

Comment: @AugSB, may be a mistake in question? Hope they meant to ask "then $Z(0,1)\ne$